# XML android layout hiding icon

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, icons

I'm writing an Android app and I've encountered a strange thing. Namely it is a visibility of my icon. It should be on the right side of the screen.

When I put it to the left it is ok and it is visible like this:

[image]

But when I put it right it looks like this:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/space_medium" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textColor="#666666" 
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:alpha=".50"
                android:src="@drawable/paprika" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textColor="#666666" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_small"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_rounded_light_blue"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#fff" /> 

    </LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some considerations:

- You don't need 2 nested LinearLayouts, a single RelativeLayout can handle all the Views (less layouts = better performances).
- Have you tried to put the image not inside an ImageView, but **directly into the TextView** (less Views = better performances)? It's called a **compound drawable**:

  android:drawableTop|Left|Right|Bottom="@drawable/your_image"

It will also prevent the Z-Index overlapping.

So, this how I'd put that together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/space_medium"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/paprika"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="#667"
            android:textSize="20sp"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textColor="#667"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button"
            android:layout_below="@id/description"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_small"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_rounded_light_blue"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="#fff"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

To set your compound drawable programmatically (once you have a reference to the TextView), just use the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` method to assign one or more compound images, as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: It worked!You are really awesome <3
Thanks for help !

Comment: I'm not awesome... just a little experienced. ;)